# Evaluate $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

I want to evaluate $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}} $ ([Joseph Bak's chapter 12 example 2](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=MKPe1Q9k-nAC&pg=PA161&lpg=PA161&dq=Joseph+Bak%27s+chapter+12&source=bl&ots=df6m0y3sJr&sig=ACfU3U3b6drxLVjCNiQWbt3DEyXR9K2A9w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiWhJ2Sl4zqAhWQi1wKHUviDTAQ6AEwAHoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=Joseph%20Bak%27s%20chapter%2012&f=false))

According to the textbook, I need to change the contour to $R$ instead of $1$. But I couldn't find reason why $\oint_{|z|=1} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}} = \oint_{|z|=R} \frac{dz}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}}$ holds for $R$ greater than 1. Can you please give me reason why it holds?

Comment: doesn't this depend on $R$? the polynomial factors into $(6z-1)(z-1)$ so if $R < 1/6$ wouldn't you always get $0$ and $R > 1$ you have both poles, and in the middle one at $1/6$

Comment: We could make that change if the integrand is analytic in the region on and between the two curves.  I can only assume this is explained somewhere earlier in the book.  Perhaps Chapter 4 or 5.

Comment: @GEdgar this integrand has a pole at $z=1$

Comment: I get poles at $1/3$ and $1/2$

Comment: $(6z^2-5x+1)=6(z-\frac{1}{2})(z-\frac{1}{3})$ so all singularities of integrand lie within $|z|<1$ @RudinWaltersky

Comment: @AlexeyBurdin Can you give a little more explanation? How the fact that singularities are inside the unit circle guarantee that I can enlarge the contour as I wish?

Comment: When you cut the plane from $1/2$ to $\infty$ and from $1/3$ to $\infty$ you can choose the branch cuts to coalesce.  This effectively gives one cut from $1/2$ to $1/3$.  The integrand is analytic outside any closed contour that encloses both branch points exactly once.  Now take the contour to be a circle of radius $R$ and let $R\to \infty$.

Comment: I edited my answer @RudinWaltersky

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer has been edited:**

It's a common trick in complex analysis to parameterise the contour, and take the limit as the contour approaches some other shape (which in general will change the value of the integral, but under certain conditions it will not change the value of the integral). For example, it's used a lot when using complex integration methods to evaluate real valued integrals.

Now, in this case, we are integrating the function ${\frac{1}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}}}$. This has two singularities which lie in the unit circle, and you can use Residue Theorem to evaluate this.

What the authour has done - he has decided to replace the unit circle with a circle of radius ${R>1}$. This is valid since, as I said before, our function is analytic on the region ${\{z \in \mathbb{C}\ |\ 1\leq |z| < R\}}$. This is indeed a Theorem (Deformation Theorem, give that bad boy a Google ;D). Since ${R>1}$ can be arbitrarily large, he's approximated the function on the $R$ circle to just ${\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}z}}$ (I guess an intuitive way of thinking about it is that as ${R}$ get's larger and larger, the function becomes closer to being ${\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}z}}$ on the ${R}$ circle). This isn't rigorous, although I'm sure it could probably be rigoursly justified.

Anyway, the integral of ${\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{1}{z}dz=2\pi i}$, and hence he's gotten

$${\oint_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}}dz=\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{1}{\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}}dz\rightarrow\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}\oint_{|z|=R}\frac{1}{z}dz=\frac{2\pi i}{\sqrt{6}}}$$

Where the ${\rightarrow}$ is being used to mean ${R\rightarrow \infty}$

Comment: I don't totally get it. Is there a name for the theorem stating that contour may be changed as long as the function is analytic on that domain? (the domain that contains both contours, before and after)

Comment: Yeah indeed the integral will remain the same. I'm not sure why you need to change the contour though? the singularities lie within the unit circle, so can't you just use the residue theorem?

Comment: Oh I took a look at the textbook. I see what the author has done. He's evaluated without using residue theorem by doing a dirty trick (namely, he's implicitly took ${R}$ to be arbitrarily large, for which ${\sqrt{6z^2-5z+1}}$ can be approximated to ${\sqrt{6}z}$)

Comment: Yeah. That's what I meant. But I still don't get it though. Why the value of integration doesn't change? Also, since the polynomial is within sqrt, so the line segment adjoining two singularities is singular as a whole, so isn't it impossibile to use Residue thm? Because it requires isolated singularities..

Comment: I'll edit my answer to explain